# Cannot figure out inputting floats or integers into my neural-network

Tags: python, arrays, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Sorry if this is a trivial question, or just plain stupid, I'm just getting started with python and neural-networks... So I made this simple neural network off a tutorial and everything's working fine, my question is how I would go about changing my input and output goal, because at the moment I don't understand why the input and output is in an array? I'm looking to do something like getting it to learn to return a 1 when a decreasing value gets to a certain point, like 0.25, and return 0 otherwise? An example would be the input being the X distance to an obstacle and it could learn to jump when it gets close enough (output of 1 = jump, output of 0 = do nothing)? (To summarize, my problem is I'm trying to find a way to input things like floats and output things like floats or integers but it only seems to take in and output np.arrays) Here's the code for reference (this works fine but I'm not sure how I should change the input and output goal...):

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0/(1+ np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1.0 - x)    


class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.input = x
        self.weights1 = np.random.rand(self.input.shape[1],4)
        self.weights2 = np.random.rand(4,1)
        self.y = y
        self.output = np.zeros(y.shape)

    def feedforward(self):
            self.layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.input, self.weights1))
            self.output = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights2))

    def backprop(self):
        d_weights2 = np.dot(self.layer1.T, (2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output)))        
        d_weights1 = np.dot(self.input.T, (np.dot(2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output), self.weights2.T) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1)))

        self.weights1 += d_weights1
        self.weights2 += d_weights2



if __name__ == "__main__":
    X = np.array([[0,0,1],
                  [0,1,1],
                  [1,0,1],
                  [1,1,1]])
    y = np.array([[1],[0],[1],[0]])
    nn = NeuralNetwork(X,y)

    for i in range(10000):
        nn.feedforward()
        nn.backprop()

    print(nn.output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know what **`batch size`** is, generally speaking, we usually input multiple samples into the NN, `batch size` is the num of samples, see, the input has **at list 2 dim** `[batch_size, fea_size]`, so we use ndarray to contain the input.

If you want input a single (mean `batch size` is 1) float(means `fea_size` is 1), you need to wrap you intput using ndarray in shape (1,1), like `np.array([[0.5]])`.

Next, the output of NN's is also in shape `[batch_size, output_size]`, it gives results for all input samples, and the `output_size` id determined by last layer's weight (in your code `self.weights2 = np.random.rand(4,1)`), this means the `output_size` is 1. So if you want a float output, you can get it from `np.output[:, 0]` for all samples.

Comment: Thank you! If I followed correctly, I need to setup a proper batch size for what I'm inputting, however, one quick question, where would I implement the np.output[:, 0] that you mentioned, and how would I set the output goal to a number dependent to X?

Comment: First `batch size` is not necessary to be set,  just make sure the the `fea_size` is correct, you can input (any, fea_size). Second, after your `for` backprop loop, you can use `np.output[:, 0]` anywhere, for example before the `print` statement, it has the shape (batch_size,) whose i-th element is the result of the i-th input sample (the i-th row in `X`). Last, each row of `y` is the goal of the corresponding row of `X`, (in your demo code, the first row `[1]` in `y` is the goal of the first row `[0, 0, 1]` in `X`, to use new data, just make sure you input the new `X, y` correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately I am still unsure as of how I would go about, for example: Getting the network to learn to return a 0 if the input doesn't equal 0.25, and if it does, then returning 1, sorry to keep bothering you! (also do you mean nn.output[:, 0] as np.output[:, 0] returns an error)

Comment: My fault, it should be `nn.output[:, 0]` rather than `np.output[:, 0]`. To achieve you goal, label `y` should satisfy `y[X!=0.25]=0, y[X=0.25]=1`, for example  `X = [[0.25], [0.666], [0.777], [0.25]], y=[[1], [0], [0], [1]]`.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much! One last question, so sorry to keep bugging you lol, but seeing as my input is an array, how would I feed in a specific value for the neural net to analyze? Currently I have `X = np.array([[0.25], [0.666], [0.777], [0.25], [0.111]]) y = np.array([[1], [0], [0], [1], [0]])` Such as feeding in an actual singular float for it to determine a resulting output for? Do I need to save a copy of the neural net and run a singular float input (such as `X = [[0.25]]`) through that?

Comment: Yes, suppose you want the result for input float 0.25, you need input `X = [[0.25]]`, but it's not necessary to copy this net, the NN are the weights `nn.weights1` and `nn.weights2`. The best way to analyze is adding an class func 
`
def inference(self, X): 
    layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(X, self.weights1))
    output = sigmoid(np.dot(layer1, self.weights2))
    return output
`
When you want to analyze a new `X`, call this function `nn.inference(X)` and get the result.

Comment: Thanks! How would I print this return value?

Comment: The return value is a ndarray, just `res = nn.inference(X)` and `print(res)` or `print(res[0, 0])`

Comment: Thank you! I am SO grateful for your help I would be completely lost lol :)

Comment: My pleasure, if I solve your problem could you accept my answer of vote for this answer? It is the best way to show gratitude on stackoverlow, hhh.

Comment: Sure! Sorry I didn't see your comment until now :)